# Acionar um submit da pagina pai, atraves de um botão dentro de uma pagina popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

A pagina atual tem um formulário para preenchimento do usuário e quando ele finaliza, é chamado um popup onde mostra as informações para o usuário e aperta um botão para confirmar as informações.
Estou chamando o popup desta forma no arquivo pointing_add.php:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="newPopup()">teste</button>
```

E trato nessa fuction:

```
function newPopup() {
        var name_cli = $('#client_name').val()
        var name_proj = $('#project_name').val()
        var name_act = $('#name_activity').val()
        var date_work = $('#date_work').val()
        var remote = $('#remote').val()
        var trip = $('#trip').val()
        var hour_in = $('#hour_in').val()
        var hour_lanch = $('#hour_lanch').val()
        var hour_out = $('#hour_out').val()
        var value_lanch = $('#value_lanch').val()
        var value_park = $('#value_park').val()
        var value_toll = $('#value_toll').val()
        var km_ida = $('#km_ida').val()
        var km_volta = $('#km_volta').val()
        var km_total = parseFloat(km_ida) + parseFloat(km_volta)
        var value_km = $('#value_km').val()
        var value_other = $('#value_other').val()
        var descricao = $('#desc_activity').val()
        varWindow = window.showModalDialog("<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/views/view_pointing.php?name_cli="+name_cli+"&name_proj="+name_proj+"&name_act="+name_act+"&date_work="+date_work+"&remote="+remote+"&trip="+trip+"&hour_in="+hour_in+"&hour_lanch="+hour_lanch+"&hour_out="+hour_out+"&value_lanch="+value_lanch+"&value_park="+value_park+"&value_toll="+value_toll+"&km_total="+km_total+"&value_km="+value_km+"&value_other="+value_other+"&descricao="+descricao, "popup", "width=1000, height=700");
    }
```

Segue o código do view_pointing.php:

```
<?php
require '../config.php';
$remote = $_GET['remote'] == 0 ? "Sim" : "Não";
if ($_GET['trip'] == 0) {
$trip = "Ida/Volta";
} elseif ($_GET['trip'] == 1) {
$trip = "Ida";
} elseif ($_GET['trip'] == 2) {
$trip = "Volta";
} else {
$trip = "Permanencia";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../assets/images/favicon.png" />
    <title>Confirmação de OS</title>
    <style>
        main {
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        body {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <head>
    </head>
    <main>
        <div>
            <h1>Autorização de OS</h1><br>
            <hr />
            <div>
                <h2>Informações do Projeto</h2>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Projeto</th>
                        <th>Atividade</th>
                        <th>Data do Serviço</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['name_cli']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['name_proj']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['name_act']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['date_work']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <h2>Informações do Apontamento</h2>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Remoto</th>
                        <th>Trajeto</th>
                        <th>Hora de Entrada</th>
                        <th>Hora de Almoço</th>
                        <th>Hora de Saida</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $remote; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $trip; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['hour_in']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['hour_lanch']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['hour_out']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <h2>Informações de Despesa</h2>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Almoço</th>
                        <th>Estacionamento</th>
                        <th>Padágio</th>
                        <th>Km Total</th>
                        <th>Valor do KM</th>
                        <th>Outras Despesas</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['value_lanch']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['value_park']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['value_toll']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['km_total']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['value_km']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['value_other']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <h2>Descrição do Apontamento</h2>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Descrição</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $_GET['descricao']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br />
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Precisava que esse botão confirmar, ativasse o submit do form apresentado no arquivo pointing_add.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para submeter o formulário da página pai você usa

```
window.opener.document.forms['name_do_form'].submit();
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado!